# plotly-Dash - how to create 3 filters based on dataset columns (drop down list can be multi select)

Tags: plotly-dash

I am new to Dash, and I don't have knowledge for css and html.

I have a requirement that is to add 3 filters for the sankey chart based on dataCenter, customer and company ID columns with dash library ,type is multi selection dropdown. so I can filter the sankey chart.
The default value for all the 3 filters I need are 'Select All'.

I have refer to some materials on page  https://dash.plotly.com/, but due to kind of reason, I am not able to successfully make it.

This is the code for dash part, and i don't know how to add call back for these 3 filters.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-multi-dataCenter-dropdown',
        options=[ {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['companyID'].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Data Center'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-multi-customer-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['Customer'].unique()]  + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Customer'),
    
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-multi-companyID-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['companyID'].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select companyID'),
    
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    
    dcc.Graph(id='uxrPerfGoalSankey',figure=fig)
])
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('my-multi-dataCenter-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('my-multi-customer-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('my-multi-companyID-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried so far, and explain what isn't working properly?

Comment: You can use 3 [dcc.DropDown](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown#multi-value-dropdown) components, one for each filter, with the property `multi=True` and a list of options that corresponds to the values of the respective column. Then, using a callback you can update the graph according to dropdown inputs (also explained on the page mentioned above).

Comment: @coralvanda , I have updated my posts, please check. I don't know how to add the correct call back for 3 filters, and the default 'select all' option in the dropdown list.

Comment: @EricLavault, I updated the code for dash part.  I tried to using the approach based on what you suggested.  I can see 3 filters  and the values based on dataframe columns on the dashboard. But how to add a default 'select all' option in 3 filters respectively in code, and how to write the correct call back?

Comment: The callback just needs to take two more `Input` values, so it has one from each dropdown. I'll add an answer for the 'select all' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a 'select all' option, you can do something like this:

```py
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='my-multi-companyID-dropdown',
    options=[
        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['companyID'].unique()
    ] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'],
    multi=True, placeholder='Please select companyID')
```

Then, in your callback, you can check for the `'allID'` value, and know that means all values. You'd set a slightly different one for each callback, so you can tell them apart.

Edit: Fix for callback. You need to make sure the number of arguments the function takes matches the number of `Input` and `State` values you assign to the callback. The callback should look like this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('my-multi-dataCenter-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('my-multi-customer-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('my-multi-companyID-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(data_value, customer_value, company_id_value):
    # function body goes here
```

Comment: thank for for the help. But sorry I still can't fully understand the callback correctly, and can't make the filters work as expected. It says error 'TypeError: update_output() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given' . I have updated my latest code for callback part in the post. Please help check.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that error. I've updated my answer to show you the fix for it.

Comment: Thanks for help. The error has gone.  I  accepted this anwser for the issue in this post only as the filters has appeared, and will create a new post for the filters doesn't work issue.